# Lagom 1.4.10 use akka 2.5.19 and works not in prod-mode

Tags: akka, lagom

I use Lagom Framework 1.4.10. A few days ago reactive-cli updated to 1.7.0 and need akka 2.5.20. But lagom using 2.5.19

So this is not working if I try to deploy it on kubernetes.

Is their a other way to upgrade Lagom with akka?

UPDATE
After upgrade to lagom 1.4.11 still no conncetion.

```
2019-02-15T09:08:26.938Z [warn] akka.cluster.sharding.ShardRegion [sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2, akkaTimestamp=09:08:26.938UTC, akkaSource=akka.tcp://application@****:2552/system/sharding/EmployeeEntity, sourceActorSystem=application] - Trying to register to coordinator at [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://application@****:2552/), Path(/system/sharding/EmployeeEntityCoordinator/singleton/coordinator)]], but no acknowledgement. Total [1] buffered messages. [Coordinator [Member(address = akka.tcp://application@*****:2552, status = Up)] is reachable.]
2019-02-15T09:08:26.939Z [warn] akka.cluster.sharding.ShardRegion [sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3, akkaTimestamp=09:08:26.938UTC, akkaSource=akka.tcp://application@****:2552/system/sharding/PermissionCatalogEntity, sourceActorSystem=application] - Trying to register to coordinator at [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://application@****:2552/), Path(/system/sharding/PermissionCatalogEntityCoordinator/singleton/coordinator)]], but no acknowledgement. Total [1] buffered messages. [Coordinator [Member(address = akka.tcp://application@****:2552, status = Up)] is reachable.]
2019-02-15T09:08:27.011Z [warn] akka.cluster.sharding.ShardRegion [sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5, akkaTimestamp=09:08:27.011UTC, akkaSource=akka.tcp://application@****:2552/system/sharding/PermissionCatalogEntity, sourceActorSystem=application] - Retry request for shard [81] homes from coordinator at [Actor[akka.tcp://application@******:2552/system/sharding/PermissionCatalogEntityCoordinator/singleton/coordinator#-2041878421]]. [1] buffered messages.
2019-02-15T09:08:27.012Z [warn] akka.cluster.sharding.ShardRegion [sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4, akkaTimestamp=09:08:27.011UTC, akkaSource=akka.tcp://application@*****:2552/system/sharding/EmployeeEntity, sourceActorSystem=application] - Retry request for shard [28] homes from coordinator at [Actor[akka.tcp://application@****:2552/system/sharding/EmployeeEntityCoordinator/singleton/coordinator#620807563]]. [1] buffered messages.
```

on a pod

A bad Request on a log GUI

```
com.lightbend.lagom.scaladsl.api.transport.TransportException: Bad Gateway (502/4502 Unknown error code)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.scaladsl.api.transport.TransportException$.$anonfun$fromCodeAndMessage$2(Exceptions.scala:223)
    at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:158)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.scaladsl.api.transport.TransportException$.fromCodeAndMessage(Exceptions.scala:223)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.scaladsl.api.deser.DefaultExceptionSerializer.fromCodeAndMessage(ExceptionSerializer.scala:114)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.scaladsl.api.deser.DefaultExceptionSerializer.deserialize(ExceptionSerializer.scala:100)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.scaladsl.client.ScaladslServiceApiBridge.exceptionSerializerDeserializeHttpException(ScaladslServiceApiBridge.scala:82)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.scaladsl.client.ScaladslServiceApiBridge.exceptionSerializerDeserializeHttpException$(ScaladslServiceApiBridge.scala:80)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.scaladsl.client.ScaladslClientServiceCallInvoker.exceptionSerializerDeserializeHttpException(ScaladslServiceClientInvoker.scala:110)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.scaladsl.client.ScaladslClientServiceCallInvoker.exceptionSerializerDeserializeHttpException(ScaladslServiceClientInvoker.scala:110)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.client.ClientServiceCallInvoker.$anonfun$makeStrictCall$3(ClientServiceCallInvoker.scala:222)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:251)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:209)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:289)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:29)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:29)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:44)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Also is their an 404 with a http request with firefox. Before upgrading to 1.4.11 and 1.7.0 their was all fine.

```
rp generate-kubernetes-resources "docker-registry.*****/workermanagement-impl:0.20-SNAPSHOT" \
          --pod-controller-replicas 3 --generate-all --deployment-type rolling \
          --registry-username **** --registry-password ***** \
          --external-service "cas_native=_cql._tcp.cassandra.avalon.svc.cluster.local" \
          --external-service "kafka_native=kafka.avalon.svc.cluster.local:9092" \
          --pod-controller-image-pull-policy Always --ingress-annotation kubernetes.io/ingress.class=traefik \
          --namespace avalon --env JAVA_OPTS="-Dplay.http.secret.key=****" | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: What's the error when you mix Lagom 1.4.10 with reactive-cli 1.7.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lagom 1.4.11 has now been released addressing this problem. See https://www.lagomframework.com/blog/lagom-1-4-11.html.

Comment: Still not working! `com.lightbend.lagom.scaladsl.api.transport.TransportException: Bad Gateway (502/4502 Unknown error code)` in a request. One pod is loggin warns. Edit the post

Comment: IMPORTANT!! Upgrade also sbt-reactive-app to 1.7.3